# Move excel row based on cell content

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an excel sheet and I want to move the entire row to another sheet and remove it from the original one based on the cell content
Here is my code:

```
function onEdit(event) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s =event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r =event.source.getActiveRange();
if(s.getName()=="Main" && r.getColumn ()== 7&& r.getValue () == "Completed"){
var row =r.getRow();
var numColumns= s.getLastcolumn();
var targetsheet= ss.getSheetByName("Completed");
var target=targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+ 1, 1);
s.getRange( row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
if(s.getName () == "Main" && r.getColumn () == 7 && r.getValue () == "Pending"){
var row =r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Pending");
var target = targetSheet.getRange( targetSheet.getlastRow ()+ 1, 1);
s.getRange( row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow( row);
}
if(s.getName ()=="Main" && r.getColumn ()==7 && r.getValue () == "Hold") {
var row= r.getRow( );
var numcolumns =s.getLastColumn()
var targetSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Hold" );
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+ 1, 1);
s.getRange(row ,1,1,numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

Iam trying to edit the onEidit function However this code is not working for me
here is the "Main" sheet[image: Main sheet]

Comment: Google sheets is not Excel.  If this is in Google Sheets then you need to adjust the question and tags appropriately.  Excel uses VBA and OfficScript for the online app.

Comment: Microsoft Excel is not Google Sheets (different companies, different products). Fixed the tags for you.

Comment: let Google = Luke Skywalker, let Microsoft = Darth Vader.  Google > Microsoft returns true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Description**

I simplified your script to suit my tastes.  This works for me.  You have to be careful to make sure you type the correct sheet name in column 7.  I would have used a Data Validation drop down list to prevent typos.

**Script**

```
function onEdit(event) {
  try {
    let sheets = ["Completed","Pending","Hold"];
    let spread = event.source;
    let source = event.range.getSheet();
    if( source.getName() === "Main" ) {
      if( event.range.getColumn() === 7 ) {
        if( sheets.indexOf(event.value) < 0) return;
        let row = event.range.getRow();
        let numColumns = source.getLastColumn();
        let target = spread.getSheetByName(event.value);
        target = target.getRange(target.getLastRow()+1,1);
        source.getRange(row,1,1,numColumns).moveTo(target);
        source.deleteRow(row)
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Simple trigger event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Hi @TheWizEd
thanks for your answer, However the code still not working for me
Is there is anything I should do after I save the code and execute it?
It gives me the following error when I try to execute it:
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined]

Comment: the code is working now, I just had to edit the cell content to another thing then rehanged it to the right content,
thanks for you help.

Comment: You can't run a trigger from the script editor the event object `event` is undefined.  Glad you finally got it working.